# How do I edit a nested model with a has_many :though relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Im on rails 4. Lets say I have three models; House, Color, and HouseColoring.

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :house_colorings
  has_many :colors, through: :house_colorings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :house_colorings, allow_destroy: true
end

class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :house_colorings
  has_many :houses, through: :house_colorings
end

class HouseColoring < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :house
  belongs_to :color
end
```

my house controller

```
class HousesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_house
  ...

  def new
    @house = House.new
    @house.house_colorings.build
  end

  def create
    @house = House.create(house_params)
    if @house.save
      redirect_to @house
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    #Gets @house from set_house
  end

  def update
    if @house.update(house_params)
      redirect_to @house
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  ...

  private

    def set_house
      @house = House.find(params[:id])
    end

    def house_params
      params.require(:house).permit(:some_parameters, house_coloring_attributes: [:color_id, :some_other_params])
    end
end
```

I have a list of colors in my db to choose from when creating a new house and a house can have multiple colors. When I go to create a new house, I choose a color and it saves just fine. The problem i'm running into is that is I edit my the house I just created and decide to change the color, it adds a new house_color record instead of changing the one I have already.

Here is my _form.html.erb partial for my house new and edit

```
<%= form_for @house do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :house_colorings do |c| %>
    ....
    <%= c.collection_select :color_id, Color.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: "Select color"} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Why is this happening? What do I need to change to make it change/update my house_coloring instead of creating a new record? Thanks.

**Edit:**

Here is an update log for what happens when I try and update a house

```
Started PATCH "/MY_PATH/houses/16" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-24 10:33:13 -0700
Processing by HousesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sfdj43ksdkjsd3434fmskwec=", "house"=>{"name"=>"house", "house_colorings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"color_id"=>"2", "id"=>"65"}, "1"=>{"color_id"=>"3", "id"=>"66"}, "2"=>{"color_id"=>"1", "id"=>"67"}}}, "commit"=>"Update House", "id"=>"16"}
  [1m[36mHouse Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "houses".* FROM "houses" WHERE "houses"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "16"]]
Unpermitted parameters: id
Unpermitted parameters: id
Unpermitted parameters: id
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "house_colorings" ("house_id", "created_at", "color_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["house_id", 16], ["created_at", Thu, 24 Oct 2013 17:33:13 UTC +00:00], ["color_id", 2], ["updated_at", Thu, 24 Oct 2013 17:33:13 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "house_colorings" ("house_id", "created_at", "color_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["house_id", 16], ["created_at", Thu, 24 Oct 2013 17:33:13 UTC +00:00], ["color_id", 3], ["updated_at", Thu, 24 Oct 2013 17:33:13 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36mSQL (0.1ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "house_colorings" ("house_id", "created_at", "color_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["house_id", 16], ["created_at", Thu, 24 Oct 2013 17:33:13 UTC +00:00], ["color_id", 1], ["updated_at", Thu, 24 Oct 2013 17:33:13 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (10.5ms)[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/houses/16
Completed 302 Found in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 12.5ms)
```

Comment: When starting a new project with the setup you have, it behaves as it should. Could you post some logs of the update action? Have you double-checked your spelling for "through" and "accepts_nested_attributes_for"?

Comment: the `through` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` are spelled correctly.

Comment: its not though its through :P

Comment: I misspelled it here, but its spelled correctly in my project, creating the house works fine and the house_coloring record is created fine in the db. My problem is when I EDIT a house and try and change the color, instead of updating/changing the existing house_coloring record, it creates a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to permit the id of the house_coloring in the params like this

```
def house_params
      params.require(:house).permit(:some_parameters, house_coloring_attributes: [:id, :color_id, :some_other_params])
end
```

I hope this ends up saving someone the headache I was dealing with.